# Automatically Cycle through hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a working version of my code here:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/brianrhea/5Hqs3/1/

When I hover over a link, it displays a hidden div in another area of the page exactly as I would like it to.

My question is how could I automatically cycle through the hidden divs if the user didn't hover over them, but then would still allow for the "hover" interaction.

Working version at the jsfiddle above, here is the code if you'd prefer.

```
<a class="sliderLinks" data-id="billing" href="#">Billing Reminders</a><br />
<a class="sliderLinks" data-id="collections" href="#">Collections</a><br />
<a class="sliderLinks" data-id="payments" href="#">Payments</a>
<br /><br />

<div id="defaultMessage">
Default Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>

<div id="textMessages">

<div class="hidden" id="billing">
Billing ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id ligula eget purus</div>

<div class="hidden" id="collections">
Collections Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="payments">
Payments orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".sliderLinks").hover(
              function(){
                  var id = $(this).data("id");
                  if(id!==undefined){
                   $("#" + id).fadeIn(500);
                  }
                  $("#textMessages").fadeIn(500);
                  $("#defaultMessage").hide();

              },function(){
                  $("#textMessages").hide();
                  $(".hidden").hide();
                  $("#defaultMessage").fadeIn(500);  
              });
      });
```

Comment: You need to do it in 2 parts: 1. Write a cycle function with setTimeout to repeat          2. stop the cycling on list hover and do the stuff you were doing, onmouseout restart the first function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to call the advance function. When the timeout is called, set the timeout again for the next item.

If a user hovers over an item, use `clearTimeout` to remove the current timeout. When the user leaves the items, start a new timeout.

**Update:**

Using your original HTML, I cobbled this together. It isn't perfect but it is basically what you asked for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var dispID = new Array("billing", "collections", "payments");
   var dispCounter = 0;
   var timer = setTimeout(iterate, 1000);

   function iterate() {
       $("#defaultMessage").hide();  
       $("#" + dispID[dispCounter]).fadeOut(500, function() {
           if (++dispCounter == dispID.length) dispCounter = 0;
           $("#" + dispID[dispCounter]).fadeIn(500);

           timer = setTimeout(iterate, 1000);
       });
   } 

   $(".sliderLinks").hover(function() {
       clearTimeout(timer);
       var id = $(this).data("id");
        if (id != null) {
            $("#" + id).siblings().fadeOut(500, function() {
               $("#" + id).fadeIn(500); 
            });
        }
    }, function() {
        timer = setTimeout(iterate, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, I've worked with that suggestion but haven't been able to implement it.

Comment: @brhea Just a question, what browser are you using to test your Javascript?

Comment: I've been using Firebug, but am still learning ... do you have a recommendation that you prefer?

Comment: @brhea I was just checking what you use. I mean so long as we aren't talking Internet Explorer you're good. Aside from that its all a matter of what you know and like. I personally prefer Opera which has its debugger built in. I'm not sure why my method is not working for you. I am currently in class so if this answer is not solved when I get home, I will hack together a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I forked your code and corrected here
http://www.jsfiddle.net/sTWCg/4/

Comment: Thanks dvhh, but that's not working for me. The text is not automatically rotating through if the user doesn't take an action.